# Binary Search in 2D Array 3

Tags: c++

I need to find a number in the 2D array. 
Columns are sorted (from smallest value to the biggest).

Here is my code:

```
const int SIZE = 4;
const int NOT_FOUND = 1;
int  binarySearch(int mat[][SIZE], int &line , int num);

void main()
{
    int num, index,  mat[SIZE][SIZE] = { 11,1,5,11,
                                         11,6,7,2,
                                         8,7,7,7,
                                         0,12,9,10 };

    int line = sizeof(mat) / sizeof(mat[0][0]);

    cout << "please type a number to search: " << endl;
    cin >> num;

    index = binarySearch(mat, line, num);

    if (index == NOT_FOUND) {
        cout << "The value: " << num << "doesn't exist in the array\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "The value: " << num << " exists in line " << line+1 
        <<" and column: " << index+1 << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}


int binarySearch(int mat[][SIZE], int &line, int num)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = SIZE - 1;
        int middle;

        while (low <= high)
        {
            middle = (low + high) / 2;

            if (num == mat[middle][j])
            {
                line = middle;
                return j;
            }
            else if (num < mat[middle][j]) {
                high = middle - 1;
            {
            else {
                low = middle + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

The program doesn't find all the numbers in the array.
Something doesn't work.

What is the problem?

Comment: Please format your code correctly! Indent four spaces tonshow code from markup.

Comment: Still weird indentations and such.

Comment: have a look [here](https://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html). I think that's what `παντα ρει` (<-the best I can do with my kbd layout :)) means

Comment: @urban /OT _@_ is quite helpful without need stressing your keyboard fu.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ :) I was reading your profile... nice one (consider adding `τα ` in front...) This comment has nothing to do with the question... I just dont know if SO has PMs

Comment: @urban No Stack Overflow doesn't support PMs, just pinging users that participate in particular posts.

Comment: If you're doing a binary search, it probably should have been a 1D array in the first place. BTW, `void main()` is illegal in C++; it should be `int main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `binarySearch` doesn't go through all the numbers, it checks the first number, so in your case **11**, then it moves to the next number, but it skips the whole row of numbers **(1, 5, 11)** and the first number in second row and then moves to the next second number which will be **6** in second row.

Since you have a Matrix of number it consists of **Rows** and **Columns**, that means you have to create two loops `for(...)`, once for the Rows and one for the Columns so you can go through all the numbers in your 2D array.

I recommend setting a *Break point* on the `binarySearch` function and going through with that, it'll help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that I see wrong in your code are ::

1) It appears that you are applying binary search to every column in your input array, and if the number is not found in the corresponding column, you increment `j` and move to the next column. 
The most important thing about binary search is "**The array in which you are searching should always be sorted**". Since here you are searching columns, all your columns shall be sorted! Which appears unsorted in the code above! Which is a major reason why you don't find most elements. So, your input array shall look something like this (if you want to apply binary search) ::

```
int mat[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0,1,5,2,
                        8,6,7,7,
                        11,7,7,10,
                        11,12,9,11 }
```

All columns sorted in ascending order here!

2) The value of the variable `NOT_FOUND` you have set it to `1` and from your function you return the column number from where you found the element. So, if you found the element in the 2D array in column `1` your program will print `Element Not Found` because the condition `if (index == NOT_FOUND)` evaluates to `true` if the element was found in column `1`. So, a better solution would be to change the value of `NOT_FOUND` to some negative value, since it can never be the column number in a valid case. Something like this ::

```
const int NOT_FOUND = -1;
```

Ideone link of code :: http://ideone.com/9cwHnY